# how to automatically deploy to aks resource created with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like a guide on how to automatically deploy to a newly provisioned  **aks** cluster after provisioning with **terraform**. for more context, i am building a one click full infrastructure provisioning and deployment all in one script. below is my structure for more understanding

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
      name                = var.cluster_name
      kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      dns_prefix          = var.cluster_name
    
      default_node_pool {
        name                = "system"
        node_count          = var.system_node_count
        vm_size             = "Standard_DS2_v2"
        type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        availability_zones  = [1, 2, 3]
        enable_auto_scaling = false
      }
    
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    
      network_profile {
        load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
        network_plugin    = "kubenet"
      }
      role_based_access_control {
        enabled = true
      }
}
```

**output.tf**

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
      depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]
      filename   = "kubeconfig"
      content    = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config_raw
}
```

**deployment.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "sdc" {
      metadata {
        name = "sdc"
        labels = {
          app = "serviceName"
          #version = "v1.0"
        }
        namespace = "default"
      }
    
      spec {
        replicas = 1
        selector {
          match_labels = {
            app = "serviceName"
          }
        }
        template {
          metadata {
            labels = {
              app = "serviceName"
              # version = "v1.0"
            }
          }
          spec {
            container {
              image = "myImage"
              name  = "serviceName"
              port {
                container_port = 80
              }
            
            }
          }
        }
      }
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks
      ]
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, my **kubeconfig** file is created and downloaded. my major headache is how to make the **terraform apply** process use the **kubeconfig** file created and also run the deployment. making my terraform script fully automated. I basically want to provision and deploy into the newly provisioned cluster all in one run.

Looking forward to good help.

Thanks guys

Comment: That should be fairly easy if you have defined the `required_providers` with `kubernetes` and the `provider "kuberentes"` blocks properly. Do you have those?

Comment: No I dont that, can you please show an example for more context

Comment: Take a look here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs.

Comment: do you mind showing a sample use. this isn't so clear. or explain how to use in my case?

Comment: It's very simple: you need a kubeconfig file to "talk" to a Kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes API requires a context. Since you haven't defined the kubeconfig file and configured the kubernetes provider, terraform does not know in which cluster to create the Deployment object. It can't get much clearer than that.

Comment: got that part for the kubeconfig file. so in my provider file,                                                                                     provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "~/.kube/config"
  config_context = "my-context"
}                                                                                                                                                         do i reference my kubeconfig file in the "config_context = kubeconfig" is this correct?

Comment: Can you add that to the question because it's hard to read it like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246833/discussion-between-ribo01-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late now, but this is how I solved it for myself. The problem I see with your approach is that you are making a local file resource. I have tried that route too, but the file gets created only at the end of the terraform apply run (once the actual state file is populated with the output values that would go into your file). Bear in mind that your approach would work if you were managing your deployment with 2 terraform flows(Independent state files, sharing the output file in the common folder for example).

The way to go around this is to use azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster.kube_config.xyz outputs in the Kubernetes provider section.

Example of deploying nginx into newly created AKS cluster, all in one go.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.3"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.42"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg-aks"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes_cluster" {
  name                = "aks-cluster"
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks-cluster"
  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster.kube_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test_ns" {
  metadata {
    name = "test"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx_deployment" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test_ns.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    replicas = 2
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "test"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "test"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.19.4"
          name  = "nginx"

          resources {
            limits = {
              memory = "512M"
              cpu    = "1"
            }
            requests = {
              memory = "256M"
              cpu    = "50m"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx_service" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test_ns.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_deployment.nginx_deployment.spec.0.template.0.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }
    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

output "nginx_service_ip" {
  value = kubernetes_service.nginx_service.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.ip
}
```